# How to trigger validation from custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to trigger my a validation that I have defined in a custom directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('validPolicyNumber', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope:'=brand',
            require: '?ngModel',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

                scope.$watch(scope.brand,function(){
                    ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);
                    ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validate)
                });
                function validate(value) {
                    var valid=false;

                    if (valid) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('validPolicyNumber', true);
                        return value;
                    }
                    ctrl.$setValidity('validPolicyNumber', false);
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The validate is triggered when changing the value in this input:

```
<input valid-policy-number="claimSearch.brand.value" type="text"
       class="form-control" ng-model="claimSearch.polNo" name="policyNumber"
       id="polNo" placeholder="Policy Number" value="" required>
```

However the validate is also dependent on another value ie brand that is on the same page:

```
<select name="brand" id="brand" class="form-control" ng-model="claimSearch.brand"
        ng-options="category as category.name for category in selectInputs.brand"
        required>
</select>
```

I would like to have the validate function triggered once changing the brand value. As you can see I tried to use a $watch for the brand value not sure if this is the right approach? How can I get the validation working when I change the brand value in the combobox?

Comment: scope:'=brand'? try to use scope: { 'brand': '=' }

Comment: I tried that not solved : (

Comment: I believe there are some errors in your approach... I did copy an in-use validator, for you take a look... it's a simple credit card validator: http://pastebin.com/4msZPLK1

Comment: Do you have a html-sample of the usage of the directive?

Comment: <input type="text" name="ccnumber" ng-model="ccnumber" required document-valid="cc"  autocomplete="off">

Comment: try to create a jsbin or plunker with your code. try to put a minimal validation on function validate(). try to use $validators, because the function of $parsers and $formatters is to convert values, isn't to validation

Comment: Hi Joaozito I got a sample here : https://plnkr.co/edit/BqHs7sCFTHwiAFYpf3hT?p=preview

Comment: So to summarize in the plunker: When changing the inputvalue the validation gets triggered in the directive but not when I change the combobox selection which is the brandvalue

Answer (score 1):

For create complex custom checks in AngularJS i recommend  this [use-from-error](http://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error).

Live example on [jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/wL9c2feo/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['use', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error/master/src/use-form-error.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <form name="myForm" use-form-error="formInvalid" use-error-expression="digit==9">
      <div ng-messages="myForm.$error" style="color:maroon">
        <div ng-message="formInvalid">You form is not valid</div>
      </div>
      <label>Your number should be even, not divisible by three and should not be 6,7,9:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="digit" name="myDigit" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="20" required use-form-error="isEven" use-error-expression="digit%2==0" />
      <span use-form-error="isDividedThree" use-error-expression="digit%3==0" use-error-input="myForm.myDigit"></span>
      <span use-form-error="formInvalid" use-error-expression="digit==7" use-error-input="myForm.myDigit"></span>
      <span use-form-error="formInvalid" use-error-expression="digit==6"></span>
      <pre>myForm.myDigit.$error = {{ myForm.myDigit.$error | json }}</pre>

      <div ng-messages="myForm.myDigit.$error" ng-messages-multiple="true" style="color:maroon">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a digit</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">Your digit is too short</div>
        <div ng-message="maxlength">Your digit is too long</div>
        <div ng-message="isEven">Your digit is even</div>
        <div ng-message="isDividedThree">Your digit is divided by three</div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```